# How can i get a year by using only days and months?

Tags: php, datetime, time

Requirements:
function arguments: - $day, $month
function should return the year.

Is this possible ?

Comment: @soden:  If its not asking too much, can we get some elaboration, and my be some answer acceptance?

Comment: Your question sounds like glass ball magic. I mean...how should we guess the year if you have only day and month?

Comment: I don't know, is it? If you mean number of months/days since a given date, then it is very possible. If by month you mean Jan, Feb, Mar, then... no.

Comment: It seems to me that this would be impossible... every year has each day of its month, with the small exception of leap years.

Comment: i have an input field with a datepicker. But the client asked for years not to be displayed. Well date('Y') should have fixed that but what if i am in 2010 and have to choose a date in 2011.

Comment: You can add the current year (let's say now, 2010) but if is not current it's impossible to guess. Don't you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the date picked is always in the future within a year, you can do this:

```
function next_date($m, $d)
{
  $s = sprintf('%02d-%02d', $m, $d);
  $y = date('Y');
  if (date('m-d') > $s) ++$y;
  return "$y-$s";
}
```

So if you pick a date between today and the end of this calendar year, it returns this year. Else it returns next year.

Such a date picker could be useful if you know the date being picked is never in the past and it's always within the next year. If that describes the type of date you are working with, then this is probably the behavior the client expects.

Otherwise, either your client is completely clueless or you misunderstood what they asked.

Answer (score 8):

No. You're not giving the function even remotely enough information to be able to determine the year. Here's why:

I was born on March 2nd. Since I've given you the day and the month, please tell me what year I was born in.

Can't do it? Neither can a computer.

Sorry to be harsh, but the question makes no sense.

Comment: thanx. Just wanted to know if it was even remotely possible

Comment: @soden: You're welcome. Again, sorry to come down so hard on you. It's really not the way I normally operate.

Comment: You may be able to determine a list of possible years if you include the weekday too, since the same date only occurs on the same weekday in some specific years.  But that's about the best you can do.

Comment: @cdhowie: I did start writing that into the answer, thinking "day" might mean "DayOfWeek" but disregarded that since without an actual "DayOfMonth" as well, it was meaningless. Also, the best you could do even with that info is return an array of possible years. You should write an answer with your suggestion though, because that might be workable if OP has the ability to get the DayOfWeek from his DateTimePicker. I'll upvote you if you do. :)